# Keep only endpoints of line with Extract Vertices

Tags: layers, qgis-3, vertices

Using QGIS 3.2, I can use the "Extract Vertices" tool to generate a layer of vertices for each line segment in my data. My data is split into line segments of between 400-500m in length (using the v.split command). Since the geography is not straight, the tool extracts numerous vertices for each line segment:

[image]

For example, the selected line segment in red has 5 associated vertices. Is there a way to keep only the endpoints of each segment? I can use the fact that "vertex_part = 0" to find one endpoint, but since my line segments vary in distance I'm not sure how to easily pick out the other end.

Comment: both, *start* and *end* points? with attributes of the parent line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Extract specific vertices tool` to extract the endpoints by inputing `0, -1` at the vertex indecies as you can see below:

[image]

The tool is located in `Processing toolbox -> Vector geometry -> Extract specific vertices tool`.

The input is a polyline composing of several segemets

[image]

Using the above tool with -1 index provides the endpoint only:

[image]

Comment: and use `0, -1` for both *start* and *end* points

Comment: @ThingumaBob that is right, however, since the OP asked for endpoint, I used `-1`

Comment: I know, just as an addition...I just kind of read that question as if OP askes for both...(I was writing the same answer but you we're faster...wanted to share my 2 cents, too ,) )

Comment: @ThingumaBob You are right, I have just noticed that he wanted both endpoints. I updated my answer. Thank you.